# Ionic Framework : Can't navigating back to my app after doing form-post to my hosting

Tags: php, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, crosswalk-runtime

I have an App which uploads a photo to a hosting by using codes below :

```
<div style="background:black" class="item item-body">
                <img ng-src="http://m.fxlegato.com/profileImages/{{datauser.email}}.jpg" align="center" style="height:80%;width:80%;margin-left:auto;margin-right: auto;display:block;">
                <form action="{{ 'http://m.fxlegato.com/profileImages/upload.php?email=' + datauser.email}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" class="light" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" />
                    <input type="submit" class="button button-positive button-block" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
                </form>
            </div>
```

When Upload button pressed, then a message from my upload.php appears. The photo is uploaded successfully, But I can't get back to my app while I am in that .php messages. This problem appears after I added the crosswalk to my app. If I not use that crosswalk, all works perfect.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IHMO, basic HTML forms, with a basic `action` are not a good solution to use on hybrid apps.

Since your are uploading a file, you should consider using a dedicated library, like one of those two:

- https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload
- https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Also, some tutorials are available to do this kind of stuff. Here is an example:

- https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/01/upload-files-remote-server-using-ionic-framework/